# How to Pass geojson array to datatable dyanamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, geojson

I want to pass one geojson file to dynamically created datatable using javascript,I am unable to identify column names in file..
  I have tried this..

> **CODE**

```
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>fC.type</th>
                <th>f.type</th>
                <th>f.prop</th>
                <th>f.geom.type</th>
                <th>geometry.coordinates.0</th>
                <th>geometry.coordinates.1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "ajax": "data/json_file.json",
        "processing": true,
        "columns": [
            { "mData": "type" },
            { "mData": "features.type" },
            { "mData": "features.properties" },
            { "mData": "geometry.type" },
            { "mData": "geometry.coordinates.0" },
            { "mData": "geometry.coordinates.1" }
        ]
    });
});
```

> **geojson File**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            40.078125,
            57.136239319177434
          ],
          [
            91.7578125,
            58.99531118795094
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[My output is as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rtFV.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually the datafile, which is valid JSON but not the structure that datatable requires.

Solution 1 : **Change the file to expected structure.**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                40.078125,
                57.136239319177434
              ],
              [
                91.7578125,
                58.99531118795094
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Solution 2 : **Use the dataSrc through which you can modify the ajax response before datatable uses it.**

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax":
    {
        "url": "json1.json",
        "dataSrc": function (json) {

            var obj = [];
            obj.data = [];
            obj.data[0] = json;

            return obj.data;
        },
    },
    "processing": "true",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "type" },
        { "data": "features.0.type" },
        { "data": "features.0.properties" },
        { "data": "features.0.geometry.type" },
        { "data": "features.0.geometry.coordinates.0" },
        { "data": "features.0.geometry.coordinates.1" }
    ]
});
```

Here what I've done is created a new object obj.
Working fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/ourqh9ts/

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the GeoJSON is not an array but an object.

Try changing your column definitions with these:

```
"columns": [
     { "data": "type" },
     { "data": "features.0.type" },
     { "data": "features.0.properties" },
     { "data": "features.0.geometry.type" },
     { "data": "features.0.geometry.coordinates.0" },
     { "data": "features.0.geometry.coordinates.1" }
]
```

Comment: I tried this,,I got an error,  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".